# Why does my procedure have error when I'm trying to do loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

i try to do loop to load data in MySQL Workbench 8.0. but it keep error and i cannot figure it out.

here is my code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;
CREATE TABLE Cars (
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Price INT
);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS load_car;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE load_car()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE counter int;
        SET counter = 1;
        START transaction;
    WHILE counter <= 10 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Cars 
        VALUES 
        ('Car-'+CAST(counter as varchar), counter*100);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END;
    END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the error?

Comment: Why are you using a loop instead of set-based operations?

Comment: ('Car-'+CAST(counter as varchar), counter*100);

the error is there. im sorry, i didnt mean to shout at anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `VARCHAR()` in `CAST()`. You need to change that to `CHAR()` and with length defined. Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;
CREATE TABLE Cars (
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Price INT
);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS load_car;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE load_car()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE counter int;
        SET counter = 1;
        START transaction;
    WHILE counter <= 10 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Cars 
        VALUES 
        ('Car-'+CAST(counter AS CHAR(255)), counter*100);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END;
    END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It's still missing the id value `default` in the INSERT STATEMENT though.

Comment: That's true @blabla_bingo and I think there's a lot more than just a couple of issue with the code.. haven't tested it though as I was just replying to the error presented. Although I'm starting to have question whether this really is a MySQL because the accepted answer still uses `CAST(counter as varchar(20))` [when it's clearly wasn't able to](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e24d0d3e3cb8046235406685fd36c1ce) .. maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Pardon me for asking @HalimaAsrar but does my suggestion really solves your issue? Or does it return a different error after that?

Answer (score 0):

Your table `Cars` has three columns, but you insert two; you need to provide a column list:

```
  INSERT INTO Cars (Name, Price)
        VALUES 
        ('Car-'+CAST(counter as varchar(20)), counter*100)
```

Also, it may not be right to cast to varchar without specifying length, be specific and give the max length.

If these comments don't resolve your problem please specify what error you get.

Comment: THANKYOUUUUUU!!!!!! this help me so much. thousands thankyou from me :)

Comment: btw, how can i generate decimal(5,2) random data?

Comment: If it helped, please accept this as answer.

Comment: Have you tried the RAND() function and cast it to DECIMAL , maybe something like CAST(RAND()*1000 as DECIMAL(5,2))? If you need further help with this it needs to be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the same statement. It's the `INSERT INTO Cars VALUES  ('Car-'+CAST(counter as varchar), counter*100);` to blame. First of all , you table `Cars` has three columns but your insert statement without defining specific columns only provides for the last two,missing the id column . If you ignore this, you may be albe to create the procedure, but it will net an error when you call it. Secondly, the cast function does not support the varchar type. In this case you can use the `concat` function which will implicit convert for your integer to string type. Try the following:
`INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (default,concat('Car-',counter), counter*100);`

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use the CHAR() Instead of Varchar() in the cast and need to specify the column names in the insert stmt.

Also, Use concat function Instead of '+' symbol.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;
CREATE TABLE Cars (
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Price INT
);
call load_car;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS load_car;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE load_car()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE counter int;
        SET counter = 1;
        START transaction;
    WHILE counter <= 10 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Cars (Name, Price)
        VALUES (concat('Car-', CAST(counter as char(10))), counter*100);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END;
    END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```